# How much less efficent would the linq technique be in the following case and could either be optimised?

Tags: .net, linq, performance, optimization

How much less efficent would the linq technique be in the following case and could either be optimised?

**Linq technique**:

```
public String FindProviderName(Int32? TrueName)
{
    String providerName = (from p in this.Providers
                           where p.TrueName == TrueName
                           select p.ProviderName).First().ToString();

    return providerName;
}
```

**Walking technique**:

```
public String FindProviderName(Int32? TrueName)
{
    String providerName = String.Empty;

    foreach (IProvider provider in this.Providers)
    {
        if (provider.TrueName == TrueName)
        {
            providerName = provider.ProviderName;
            break;
        }
    }

    return providerName;
}
```

Comment: If `ProviderName` is `string`, you don't need to call `ToString()` on it.

Comment: That's right but the compiler would know that and not bother to run it in IL?

Comment: @Carnotaurus it will run it, but it is just a callvirt to "return this", so pretty fast

Comment: Oh, I thought the compiler would be intelligent enough not to compile such a superfluous statement. So, I'll give him an upvote.

Comment: @Carnotaurus - the compiler also expects the programmer to be smart enough not to *add* superfluous statements :) in reality it removes some, not all, silliness.

Comment: @Marc - Thanks for that comment :) I probably overlooked it at the time I wrote the code.

Comment: Is this linq-to-objects? Or some database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is LINQ-to-objects, they'll both be pretty fast. If you want faster, consider a `Dictionary<int,string>` and use `TryGetValue(...)`. Obviously you need to pre-generate the dictionary, perhaps via ToDictionary().

Note that the two examples shown are different when there is no match; one throws; one returns an empty string. Also, there is no need to call ToString() on a string.

---

Re the faster version (comments); you need a field,

```
Dictionary<int,string> lookup;
```

And at some point prior to use (or after data changes) you need to populate it:

```
lookup = providers.Where(p => p.RealName != null)
    .ToDictionary(p => p.RealName.Value,
        p => p.ProviderName);
```

Then your lookup would be like:

```
string providerName;
if(realName == null ||
    !lookup.TryGetValue(realName.Value, out providerName))
    return null;
return providerName;
```

Comment: Yeah, the two techniques do not do exactly the same thing - could you please give me an example of a faster implementation of either?

Answer (score 1):

You have the code, if you want to know how efficient it is, just measure it.

Of course, people quite often worry about efficiency of code, when they shouldn't. Isn't readability more important? Is this the code that slows you down?

That being said, the firs code could be made slightly faster like this:

```
public String FindProviderName(Int32? TrueName)
{
    String providerName = this.Providers
                              .First(p => p.TrueName == TrueName)
                              .Select p.ProviderName);

    return providerName;
}
```

And the second one may be made faster by using `for` instead of `foreach` (if your collection type is `List<T>` or an array.

Both those optimizations most likely won't have any measurable effect, though.

Comment: Yes, I quess rewriting the linq as a more basic lamdba would improve the speed slightly... And yes, this.Providers is as IList<IProvider>